# Reading and formatting issues in python

Tags: python, linux, bash

New to the site, hopefully my question isn't missing to many details or being too vague. Essentially i'm running a netbackup script, to create a new file:

```
subprocess.call('/usr/openv/netbackup/bin/goodies/available_media > /var/log/nbu/available_media' + adate, shell=True)
```

[image: The output of this file looks like this]

I want to then format this and input it into another file using out.write, that specifies the pool name e.g "Auth Pool", "Web Pool" etc. Use count to find out how many tapes are in a state of "AVAILABLE" "FULL" "FROZEN" for each pool.

```
#Pool #Full #Avail #Frozen
AUTH  100   5      23
```

All i've managed so far is the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import os
import sys

date = datetime.now()
adate = '%s%s%s' % (date.year, date.month, date.day)

subprocess.call('/usr/openv/netbackup/bin/goodies/available_media >    /var/log/nbu/available_media' + adate, shell=True)

log = open('/var/log/nbu/available_media' + adate, 'r')
    text = log.read()
    auth = text.split('Auth_Offsite', 1)[0]
    notapes = auth.count('AVAILABLE')
```

Currently my knowledge restricts me to just counting AVAILABLE tapes for the first pool by using split. I'm new to python so please be gentle :P
All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if your are experiencing difficulties in converting  a sample picture to raw text use this link https://www.newocr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty that should roughly do what you want, assuming that your log file is tab separated. If you're new to python, some of the functions might be new to you, but it should give you some ideas about what you might want to google for at least.

```
log = open('/var/log/nbu/available_media' + adate, 'r')

# Splits on newline chars, skips the titles and ----- lines
lines = log.readlines()[2:] 

# Break up each line by field
lines = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in lines]

# Going to form a dictionary mapping pool names to dictionaries of tape state counts
states_dict = {}
all_states = set()
for line in lines:
    if len(line) == 1:
        current_pool = line[0]
        states_dict[current_pool] = {}
    elif len(line) > 1:
        state = line[-1]
        states_dict[current_pool][state] = states_dict[current_pool].setdefault(state, 0) + 1
        all_states.add(state)

all_states = sorted(list(all_states))

# write output
with open('output_file_name.txt','wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write('Pool\t' + '\t'.join(all_states) + '\n')
    for pool in states_dict:
        outfile.write(pool)
        for state in all_states:
            outfile.write('\t' + states_dict[pool].setdefault(state, 0))
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: This looks at lot of what i need thank you! Lots to research and learn :)

Answer (score 0):

**USING PYTHON**

```
#!/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function
import re
header_type=None
my_file=open("/usr/openv/netbackup/bin/goodies/available_media","r")
results={"Auth pool":[],"Web pool":[],"Support pool":[]}
for line in my_file:
    if re.search("^ *Auth pool *$",line):
        header_type=re.search("^ *Auth pool *$",line).group()
    if re.search("^ *Web pool *$",line):
        header_type=re.search("^ *Web pool *$",line).group()
    if re.search("^ *Support pool *$",line):
        header_type=re.search("^ *Support pool *$",line).group()
    if header_type in results:
        tmp=line.split()
        if len(tmp)>=8 and tmp[8] in ["FULL","FROZEN","AVAILABLE"]:
            results[header_type].append(tmp[8])
new_file=open("/var/log/nbu/available_media","w")
new_file.write("#pool\t\t#full\t#Avail#Frozen\n")
for i in results:
    new_file.write(i+"\t")
    for j in ["FULL","FROZEN","AVAILABLE"]:
        counts=len([state_type for state_type in results[i] if state_type==j])
        new_file.write(str(counts)+"\t")
    new_file.write("\n")
new_file.close()
```

Since this question was tag under bash (I am using there is awk scripting language on your linux OS)

**USING AWK**

create a file name `awkscript` and place the following codes

```
#!/bin/awk 
BEGIN{OFS="\t\t";print("pool","full","frozen","avail")}{
if($0~/Auth pool/){
    full=frozen=avail=0;
    while(!($0~/Web pool|Support pool/) && getline){
        if($9=="FULL"){full++;};if($9=="FROZEN"){frozen++};
        if($9=="AVAILABLE"){avail++}
    };
    print("Auth pool",full,frozen,avail)
}
if($0~/Web pool/){
    full=frozen=avail=0;
    while(!($0~/Auth pool|Support pool/) && getline){
        if($9=="FULL"){full++;};if($9=="FROZEN"){frozen++};
        if($9=="AVAILABLE"){avail++}
    };
    print("Web pool",full,frozen,avail)
}
if($0~/Support pool/){
    full=frozen=avail=0;
    while(!($0~/Auth pool|Web pool/) && getline){
        if($9=="FULL"){full++;};if($9=="FROZEN"){frozen++};
        if($9=="AVAILABLE"){avail++}
    };
    print("Support pool",full,frozen,avail)
}
}
```

run script in your bash shell

```
awk -f <path to awkscript> '/usr/openv/netbackup/bin/goodies/available_media'
```

**NOTE THIS WILL PRINT RESULTS IN SHELL**

You can simply redirect output to a file

```
awk -f 'path to awkscript' '/usr/openv/netbackup/bin/goodies/available_media' > new_file
```